# What is this interesting weed growing in a yard in Northeast Ohio?

Tags: identification, weeds, yard

I wanted to see what it grew into. It's really a pretty interesting plant, about 6 feet tall with a plume of flowers at the top. These pics are from several years ago and I've discovered this thing is really aggressive if you are stupid and let it grow to full size and spit out seeds. But still, pretty cool looking. I would like to know what it's called and the latin name if possible.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a lot of these, and think GardenerJ has properly identified it. I find it interesting too. It towers over everything else in the yard and blooms late in the season, after the other perennials have gone by. The little flowers are good fall food for bees and butterflies. It has surprisingly short roots, so even if you let it grow to its full height, it's very easy to pull out. That also means that if youngsters start popping up where you don't want them, a quick tug will get them out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [*Conyza canadensis*](http://weedid.missouri.edu//weedinfo.cfm?weed_id=115) to me. Common names include Horseweed and Marestail. It grows to upwards of 6 feet in one tall stem, before branching to produce many small white flowers which then proceed to produce LOTS of tiny seeds with little white tufts to help it spread in the wind. Leaf shape of your weed appears to match up, long with a few serrations along the edge.

It's becoming an increasingly troublesome pest in agricultural settings because many populations have developed immunity to Glyphosate.

Comment: I did a google search and I couldn't find any pictures with the full plume of flowers. But it looks close anyway.